# How do we pass a ref of an old api component (react-native-gesture-handler TouchableHighlight) to requireExternalGestureToFail (waitFor equivalent)?

Tags: react-native-gesture-handler

I have a combination of old api components, like `TouchableHighlight`

example:

```
<TouchableHighlight
        ref={
          touchableRef
        }
       onPress={onPress}
>{children}<TouchableHighlight/>
```

and then I have a new type of `GestureDetector` component:

```
const gestureConfig = Gesture.Tap()
        .requireExternalGestureToFail([touchableRef])
        .onStart(onTap);
        
return (
   <GestureDetector gesture={gestureConfig}>
      <View>...
```

This is not working. If I replace `TouchableHighlight` with a `TapGesturehandler` this does work, but I need the `TouchableHighlight` functionality, therefore the question is, how do I make `GestureHandler` (new api) work with old api components like `TouchableHighlight`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward solution since `requireExternalGestureToFail` in the GestureHandler API expects an instance of a `GestureHandler` component (like `TapGestureHandler`or `PanGestureHandler`), not a ref to a non-GestureHandler component like `TouchableHighlight`.

### Workaround

You can wrap your `TouchableHighlight` with a `GestureHandler` component that take off its behavior:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { TapGestureHandler, GestureHandlerGestureEvent } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

function CustomTouchableHighlight(props) {
  const { onPress, children } = props;

  const handleTap = (event: GestureHandlerGestureEvent) => {
    // do what you need to before calling onPress
    onPress(event);
  };

  return (
    <TapGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleTap}>
      <View>{children}</View>
    </TapGestureHandler>
  );
}
```

```js
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const onTap = () => {
    // ...
  };

  const touchableRef = React.useRef();

  const gestureConfig = Gesture.Tap()
    .requireExternalGestureToFail([touchableRef])
    .onStart(onTap);

  return (
    <CustomTouchableHighlight ref={touchableRef} onPress={() => console.log('TouchableHighlight pressed')}>
      {/* Children */}
    </CustomTouchableHighlight>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response, but then I loose the `TouchableHighlight` functionality (coloring the backgound upon tap) which is the point of using it in the first place...

Is your answer full? I see you're importing `TouchableHighlight` but you're not really using it anywhere.

Comment: oh I wanted to wrap `children` within it `<TapGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleTap}><View><TouchableHighlight {...props}>{children}</TouchableHighlight></View></TapGestureHandler>`

Comment: but doesn't that mean that TapGestureHandler will catch the tap and so it won't be propagated to TouchableHighlight?

I'll try that and post back.